# Conditionally formatting greatest value in range

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I want to  have the greatest value in a row be colored. I know I can do it with conditional formatting I'm just not sure what the custom rule should be.

I have data points in row 8 of columns C-G, the data points change every day as teams earn more points.

I've tried:

```
=C8 < D8 < E8 < F8 < G8
```

that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select C8:G8, Format, Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is**:

```
=C8=max($C8:$G8)
```

choose your formatting and <kbd>Save rules</kbd>.

Comment: I know it's been a while, I had actually forgotten about this question and came back to this page when searching for a solution to this very problem... again! So thanks for answering back in February, it helped me out today!